# Unable to check a mdadm RAID1 array, says the file system's read only?

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

I recently migrated a RAID1 from a CentOS 5 system to a CentOS 6 system and ever since when I attempt to perform a check I get the following:

```
$ echo 'check' > /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action
-bash: /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action: Read-only file system
```

This actually shows up from a CRON too, specifically, `/etc/cron.d/raid-check`. this is included in the `mdadm` RPM:

```
$ rpm -ql mdadm | head -5
/etc/cron.d/raid-check
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mdmonitor
/etc/sysconfig/raid-check
/lib/udev/rules.d/63-md-raid-arrays.rules
/lib/udev/rules.d/65-md-incremental.rules
```

Here I'm running the same command that's used by the CRON:

```
$ raid-check
/usr/sbin/raid-check: line 96: /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action: Read-only file system
```

This typically runs once a week and sends an email which is what originally alerted me to the issue. But at any rate I'm at a loss why this RAID seems to be unable to be checked.

The RAID seems fine on inspection though.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md127 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      976759936 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I point this out only because while googling I found this thread regarding a bug in `mdadm` but this was for a older version of `mdadm`.

- [Debian Bug report logs - #380746
  checkarray: E: /sys/block/md_d1/md/sync_action not writeable.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=380746)

#### Version info

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

$ rpm -q mdadm
mdadm-3.3-6.el6_6.1.x86_64

$ mdadm --version
mdadm - v3.3 - 3rd September 2013
```

Comment: Umm... does `/proc/mounts` say `ro` for `sysfs`?

Comment: @frostschutz - ah good point, shows it as ro. I've not seen this before, why is that? Searching would seem like it might be an issue with docker: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @frostschutz's comment the issue appears to be due to `/sys` being mounted as readonly (ro). This was evident through this command:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts |grep sys
sysfs /sys sysfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
```

This appears to be an issue with docker. I found this issue titled: [sysfs goes into readonly mode with host networking #7101](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7101). A workaround to the issue is to remount `/sys` read-write (rw) like so:

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /sys
```

Looking through the issues in docker's issue tracker it's unclear to me whether this is intentionally being left this way or not. The workaround is good enough for me for the time being but this seems like a bug to me.

Comment: On Centos 6.6 the command for remount is `mount -o remount,rw -t sysfs sysfs /sys`

Comment: What's weird is that sysfs on my CentOS 6.6 is "rw" but the above command makes the raid-check work.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @e40 - since dealing w/ this issue I've seen that behavior as well.